# How to get rid of the first concatenation symbol

Tags: vb.net

I'm looping a table database to catch the first name of some rows

The code is like:

```
Try
While (readerFirstName.Read())
    SearchedName = readerFirstName("parteA")
    CombinatedNames = CombinatedNames & " & " & SearchedName
End While

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

And the desired result si something like

Mike & Eric & Tom

but I get

& Mike & Eric & Tom

I think I can get rid of the first " &" after the string formation using String.TrimStart

**but there's a better way to cut the first "& "?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing your loop:

```
While (readerFirstName.Read())
    SearchedName = readerFirstName("parteA")
    CombinatedNames = CombinatedNames & " & " & SearchedName
End While
```

With this one:

```
Dim names As New List(Of String)()
While (readerFirstName.Read())
    names.Add(readerFirstName("parteA"))
End While
CombinatedNames = String.Join(" & ", names)
```

The main idea here is to use the [`String.Join` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to concatenate the single names in one single operation. That method acts on collections, so you will first have to read the single items into a collection `names`.

This method will take care to add the separator string `" & "` *between* items, never before the first or after the last, so you will not end up with a leading or trailing separator (unless you have an empty item in your list).

P.S.: If you happen to know beforehand how many names will be read from `readerFirstNames`, you could optimise memory usage of my suggested code by passing the name count to the `List(Of T)` constructor (as the `capacity` parameter).

Comment: The solution worked very well!! I was not sure about how to create one array of undefined number of items. I don´t know how many items will be on every loop but the database is small, maybe no more than 1000 items so I think the memory will not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the contains in combine string before adding text in it

```
While (readerFirstName.Read())
   SearchedName = readerFirstName("parteA")
   If Not isNullOrEmpty(CombinatedNames) Then
      CombinatedNames = CombinatedNames & " & " & SearchedName
   Else
      CombinatedNames = SearchedName
   End If
End While
```

Comment: @fedeteka: If you go with this option, may I suggest that you look into [the `StringBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx). Repeated string concatenation in a loop would be a typical use case for this class; it is more efficient, memory-wise.

Comment: @JaydipJ Worked fine too. Thanks

Comment: @stakx Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are the usual way to do it, but here are few lazier alternatives:

this will remove the first 3 characters:

```
CombinatedNames = Mid( CombinatedNames , 4 )
```

this will trim  and `&` from the beginning of the string:

```
CombinatedNames = CombinatedNames.TrimStart(" "c, "&"c)
```

Comment: That's a nice and easy solution which works well when you know exactly what characters to remove. Just one note: The second `TrimStart`-based approach could in theory mutilate the first item, if that one starts with spaces or ampersands.

Comment: CombinatedNames = Mid( CombinatedNames , 4 )  worked fine too but with number 3 on my case

Answer (score 2):

or you can just read the first record and then concatenate the rest:

```
CombinatedNames = If(readerFirstName.Read, readerFirstName!parteA.ToString, "")
While readerFirstName.Read
    CombinatedNames &= " & " & readerFirstName!parteA.ToString
End While
```